# Removed .live() $(document).bind('click',selector) problems

Tags: bind, jquery

Im using

```
$(document).bind('click','.q',function(e){console.dir(e.target);});
```

my html is as so:

```
<div class="b"style="width:1000px;height:1000px">
    <div class="q"style="width:10px;height:10px"></div>
    <div class="q"style="width:10px;height:10px"></div>
    more .q added later...

</div>
```

but when I click anywhere on .b (before a .q is appended) i get my console giving me the dir for e.target of .b

**why?**

I am using this code because live() is now removed.

So my code would have been

```
$('.q').live('click',function(e){console.dir(e.target);});
```

Comment: Use `.on()` not `bind()`

Comment: Which version of Jquery are you using? Do you get the same results when you use `.on` instead?

Comment: try substituting `.bind` with `.on`

Comment: im using the new jquery 2

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on -- there's no provision for a `selector` argument with [`.bind`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

Comment: `bind` was never meant for delegated events. The old api was `delegate` now it's `on`.

Comment: @GurpreetSingh, _"...but when I click anywhere on .b **(before a .q is appended)**..."_ my emphasis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bind` doesn't support delegate events so your second parameter is the [`eventData`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/#bind-eventType-eventData-handlereventObject).
You should use `on` instead of `bind`:

```
// Not document for better performance.
$('div.b').on('click','.q', function(e){console.dir(e.target);});
```

---

You can reach the `eventData` parameter with: `e.data`, if you console it you will see `".q"` in the console.

Answer (score 1):

in [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)  syntax like

```
$(document).bind('click',function(e){console.dir(e.target);});
```

exist so 
change

```
$(document).bind('click','.q',function(e){console.dir(e.target);});
```

with

```
$(document).on('click','.q',function(e){console.dir(e.target);});
```

reference **[On](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** and **[bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)**